# Calling current Joomla username in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am making a small game in flash, I would like to track scores but I cant figure out how to call the current username from joomla using actionscript. (creating the game in flex3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use AMFPHP to connect to your Joomla setup.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/4820